# How to make UIControl looks different when disabled?

Tags: uibutton, uicontrol

I know that UIButton can look a little greyed out when disabled.

How would I do so for UIButton.

Basically I wanna do:

```
-(void) selfUpdateLikeDislikeorBookmark:(NSString *) URL
{
    self.Favorite.enabled=false;
    self.Ilikethis.enabled=false;
    self.Ihatethis.enabled=false;
    [[NSOperationQueue new] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [BGGrabClass JsonParser:URL];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            self.Favorite.enabled=true;
            self.Ilikethis.enabled=true;
            self.Ihatethis.enabled=true;
        }];
    }];
}
```

The Iikethis and Ihatethis look the part. However, self.Favorite looks exactly the same because it's a UIControl rather than UIButton.

How to take a view and dim it? Set alpha =.5? what?

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass the UIControl and hook into its enabled property. Here you can set the alpha to whichever values you need, based on if it has just been enabled/disabled.

Example in Swift and using a UIButton:

```
override var enabled: Bool {
    didSet {
       self.alpha = enabled ? 1 : 0.33
    }
}
```